# How to reduce the running time of a spark job that does SVD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a huge sparse matrix (it has ~300k rows and columns and each row has ~7000 nonzero values) which I need to decompose using singular value decomposition (SVD). I have used the "computeSVD" method of the class "pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.IndexedRowMatrix" for that purpose and it took 28 hours to execute (I have used the maximum number of available executors and memory).

The data that the spark job is reading from has the format "RowIndex(int), ColumnIndex(int), MatrixEntry(float)", that is "1,2,0.5" would mean that the matrix has the value 0.5 at the first row and the second column.

Of course I would like to reduce the running time of the spark job if I can and to that end I thought of changing the "MatrixEntry" to an integer type by (for instance) multiplying every entry with 100 and rounding it down to the closest integer. (e.g. converting 0.123 to 12).

1) Would that help me at all?

2) Any other suggestions to reduce the running time?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use the computeSVD on 23Mx100k matrix with sparsity of 0.003. I use RowMatrix for the input and I predict it takes 26 hours. It seems very slow and first question but I am trying the below configurations right now.  conf.set("spark.rdd.compress","true")
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").                          conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "1000g")               Would you please share the resource you use on spark to have a comparison?

Comment: Hey, I did not change those configurations, so the default values (whatever they are) should have been the case in my spark job. The configurations that I modified were "--conf=spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=200 --conf=spark.executor.memory=12g --conf=spark.driver.memory=8192M"

Comment: Also, I tried to use "stochastic_svd" function from "gensim.models.lsimodel" and it seems to be significantly faster than spark! The algorithm that spark uses might be an outdated one, I am not sure...

Comment: Thanks for the update, would you please send me your code you used on gensim?

Comment: Check the stochastic_svd method here:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html

I don't have a code snippet at hand but it is pretty straightforward to implement. Once you have the (nonreduced) sparse matrix you apply the stochastic_svd method and it returns a list with two elements. First one is $U$ and second one is $\Sigma$, following the notation from wiki page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem